# How to add material icons

Tags: angular, google-material-icons

I'm trying to use Outlined material icons in my app. I can't seem to properly import them. I can only use the noramal filled icons. I want to be able to use outlined icons like [this example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qrgvevvxgyp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmaterial-module.ts).

In the example I can use the `done_outline` Icon. How did they import all of the icons?

In my app I installed `npm install material-design-icons`

and I have imported `MatIconModule` in my `app.module.ts` but I still can't use any outline icons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two solutions.

1) First solution.

1. Link font element in your index file

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
```

Or outline version :

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Outlined"
  rel="stylesheet">
```

2. You can use it in your template

```html
<i class="material-icons">face</i>
```

2) Solution with material package

1. You have to install the material package

> npm install @angular/material

2. Reference into app.module

```js
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
```

3. use it now

```html
<mat-icon>face</mat-icon>
```

Demo :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-psj1hy

Comment: Using the 2nd option still displays only solid icons by default which is the OP's problem. How do you display outlined icons using the material package?

Comment: Replace link url by "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons+Outlined" 

After you can use <mat-icon class="material-icons-outlined">face</mat-icon>

if you dont want add class material-icons-outlined, add directly in your styles.css : 

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons Outlined';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
}